Iterate over indices in multinomial expansion
Context: In the multinomial expansion, the valid indices [k1, k2, ... kr] for each term fulfill the equation n = k1 + k2 + ... + kr. Given r and n, I'm trying to iterate over all terms. For that, I need a way to get every valid index set.
Example for r = 2 and n = 3:
[0 3], [1 2], [2 1], [3 0]

I tried to treat the valid arrays as numbers in base n+1, where I increment the number in the base by 1 and then check if the sum of all digits equals n.
To save time and memory, my function doesn't take r and n as inputs but just a previous valid index set.
function out_set = getNextExponent(inp_set) 
    % inp_set is a valid exponent
    % returns the next valid exponent set of a multinomial expansion
    % Examples:
    % getNextExponent([0, 0, 3]) = [0, 1, 2]
    % getNextExponent([0, 2, 1]) = [1, 1, 1]
    % getNextExponent([3, 0, 0]) = error
    % disp(getNextExponent([1, 0, 3, 5, 0])) = [1, 0, 4, 0, 4]
    % disp(getNextExponent([100, 29, 29, 0, 0, 0])) = [100, 30, 0, 0, 0, 28]
    
    % Get the parameters
    n = sum(inp_set); 
    base = n+1; % exponent list is a number in base n+1

    % Check if it is the last valid index set
    out_set = zeros(size(inp_set));
    out_set(1) = n;
    if isequal(inp_set, out_set)
        error('Last exponent already reached')
    end

    % Loop until next valid set is found
    while true
        % Add one to the set
        carry = 1;
        index = length(inp_set);
        while carry == 1
            if inp_set(index)+1 < base
                inp_set(index) = inp_set(index)+1;
                carry = 0;
            else 
                inp_set(index) = 0;
                index = index-1;
            end
        end
        % Is the next valid exponent reached?
        if sum(inp_set) == n
            break;
        end
    end    
    out_set = inp_set;
end

However, this is extremely inefficient. Are there better ways to iterate over each valid set?

Edit: I don't know if it's helpful, but this is the same problem as putting n identical objects in r boxes. So the number of possible arrays is always (n+r-1 choose r-1).

Do you really need to iterate? That is, would it be acceptable to generate all coefficients at once as rows in a matrix? Or is n so large that that's infeasible?  If it is feasible to generate them all at once, take a look here

@LuisMendo My code gets slow really quickly for even small n. So the linked solution is definitely better. Thanks!

Install combinator.m written by Matt Fig, along with related support files.
combinator.m is available here
As you have already pointed out your question is the same as solving n+r-1 choose r-1 combinations (without repetition).
Please comment whether combinator.m is useful to speed up your things

OP needs only the combinations that sum to n.

haifisch is asking for an efficient way to caculate nchoosek, which happens to be combinator.m originally written by a guy named Schwarz and that Matt Fig took over
